# How to use React only at server side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering, webpack-hot-middleware

I decided to give a shot at just using React only for server side rendering of my components written in JSX.

I decided to eliminate React on the client side as there is not much client side interaction and I thought of adding it later only if needed.

I have couple of questions on this approach though:

- How to use plain simple vanilla JavaScript at the client side? I'm still using JSX for my components. Any simple example, like handling a button click via event listener?
- Bringing the entire hot module replacement experience with this approach. Right now i am using `webpack --watch` and then restarting node server on any files changes as also stated in [this](https://github.com/webpack/docs/issues/45#issuecomment-303861127) comment. Also, where it's just pure SSR, how to refresh the screen? Right now I don't have to restart my server, but I have to still refresh my screen to reflect my changes.

Has anyone been successfully able to use [`webpack-hot-middleware`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-hot-middleware) in this approach, where it's just pure SSR?

Comment: For your first question, it's basically how you would add JavaScript to any static HTML rendered on the server-side, be it rendered with a PHP framework or React. Once the HTML is on the client, it doesn't really matter where it came from.